# App Force Closing as soon as I try to Put ads in it

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I am creating an app. It is force closing as soon as I try to go to the activity which contains the

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.adview
.......
/>
```

I have installed the google play services from sdk manager and added the google play services.jar file to my Build Path. Note. I am using Eclipse and not android Studio.

My Manifest.xml. I have declared the INTERNET permission tag:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.additiontables"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity
        android:name=".Addition_Tables"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".About_Me"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about__me" >
    </activity>
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="6111000" />

<activity
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</application>
```

Here is my Activity.xml file :- I am not sure whether I have to use com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView or Just com.google.ads.AdView.-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.additiontables.About_Me" >

 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    googleads:adSize="BANNER"
    googleads:adUnitId="(My Id)" />
```

I am very upset.:(

Please Help.

Thanks In Advance :)

Note. I have googleplayservices.jar in Refrenced libraries.

Comment: r u using play Store lib

Comment: paste your logcat error?

Comment: Please provide your logcat error.>

Comment: Both of the below answers need to be implemented.

Comment: @IAmTheSquidward  Please tell me how to get only the error from the logcat else it is tooooooo big to post in My question.

Comment: @BhadreshDevani Please tell me how to get only the error from the logcat else it is tooooooo big to post in My question

Comment: @Dev Please tell me how to get only the error from the logcat else it is tooooooo big to post in My question

Comment: @DibyamKumar did you add play services as a lib?

Comment: Yes, I mean I added it through External Jars And Now It is in my Referenced Libraries.

Comment: go to ddms-> then select your package name under your device,, and check logcat it will show you error and paste that eror here.

Comment: or let me know if you want a workaround via java code.

Comment: @Dev, Sorry but what is DDMS?

Comment: In logcat tab filter log by your package name. To do so press Green[+] button on left panel and provide your package name. Then place your logcat here.

Comment: My Logcat remains empty when I do so @BhadreshDevani

Comment: @DibyamKumar are you done?

Comment: @Dev as I said, my logcat remains empty when I do so.

Comment: did you try the way i told u? did you check my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Do not hardcode the Google Play Services version number.  Use `@integer/google_play_services_version` or it will throw an `IllegalStateException` on the wrong version.

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

See [`Setting Up Google Play Services`](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html?csw=1) for more info.

Comment: When I do so, I get an error that error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/
 google_play_services_version').

Comment: I would try cleaning and recompiling, also look @ the link I added to the answer.

Comment: Looking at your edit, you should not be referencing a jar, but a library project when using Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

use in your Activity class

```
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.ad);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

[Admob](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/banner)

Comment: may be your project error now admob not give any error

Answer (score 0):

you can use alternate method if your app is crashing due to latest admob

```
TableRow TR = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.TR);
    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(getString("your admob id here"));
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    TR.addView(adView);

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

xml code

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/TR"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Manifest file

```
<activity
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="5089000" />
```

Comment: Same Problem with this also.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private AdView adView;
 RelativeLayout view_for_ads; // take a relative layout in your layout at the bottom of screen
```

## in oncreate

```
adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("your id");
AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
view_for_ads = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_for_ads);
view_for_ads.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
view_for_ads.addView(adView);
adView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
```

## in xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_for_ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

## in manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

## now add google play services

right click-> import-> existing code-> sdk\extras\google\google_play_services
   also add GP services in your workspace by checking checkbox